# Inner product justification with an example

Tags: inner-products

i would need an explanation with an example on why is the inner product defined as it is and not like a dot product:

\begin{align}
\text{inner pr.:}& & &\boxed{a\cdot b = a_1\overline{b_1} + a_2\overline{b_2}+...a_n\overline{b_n}}\\
\text{dot pr.:}& & &\boxed{a\cdot b = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2+...a_nb_n}
\end{align}

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors) it says:

> For vectors with complex entries, using the given definition of the
>   dot product would lead to quite different properties. For instance the
>   **dot product of a vector with itself would be an arbitrary complex
>   number, and could be zero without the vector being the zero vector**.

Can anyone provide me an example on this and show me how the definition for inner product above solves this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** With $u = (1+i, 0)$, what is the dot product $u\cdot u$?

**Hint:** With $v = (1, i)$, what is the dot product $v \cdot v$?

How do we classify all 2-d vectors such that $v \cdot v = 0$?

Comment: Thank you. Is there any good case for 3-D vectors describing this? I need 2 **different** 3-D vectors and a proof of this on them.

Comment: I get $u \cdot u = 2i$ if i calculate it like a dot product and i get $u \cdot u = 2$ if i calculate it as a inner product. Then for $v$ i got $v\cdot v = 0$ if i calculated it as a dot product and $v\cdot v = 3$ if i calculated it as an inner product. Is this good justification for using definition for inner product as it is?

Comment: @71GA It's not that hard to create 3-D vectors once you understand this example.

Comment: I am trying to think that an inner product can only be aplied to vectors so first i need a **complex vector**. And i try to think of a complex vector as a column matrix with **complex numbers** (at least one has to be ) like this one: $$\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}1+3i\\2-i\\ 3\end{pmatrix}$$ and here complex numbers are $v_1=1+3i,\, v_2=2-i,\,v_3 = 3$. So now i can use theese to calculate inner product $v\cdot \overline{v} = v_1\overline{v_1}+v_2\overline{v_2}+v_3\overline{v_3}$ which is **always real** (and **this** is what we wanted it to be so now i understand why this definition is OK).

Comment: I forgot to say that inner product $v\cdot \overline{d}$ isn't demanded to be $\mathbb{C}$, so there isn't any problem here anymore. Is my thinking mathematically correct?

Comment: @71GA Those work. Alternatively, you can just append 0 as the third coordinate of those 2 vectors that I gave, since 2-D sits inside 3-D.